# PHP mysql star rating

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm following the tutorial found [here](http://devzone.co.in/simple-rating-system-using-css-jquery-ajax-php-mysql/) and I can't seem to figure out how to have the stars filled in from the ratings in the db. Basically, I want the current ratings and count of how many ratings to show before the users submits his/her own rating.
I do not want to dynamically build the product list for which I need the rating, I just need the id to post and the rating counts to generate per data-id...

--UPDATE I am able to post the rating but I need to assign an id to each product. I can get the values for just one value but I think I need to assign a var so that I can pull them for any given product

Products:

```
<div class="store-item-rating text-warning rate-ex1-cnt" id ="1">
    <div id="1" class="rate-btn-1 rate-btn"></div>
    <div id="2" class="rate-btn-2 rate-btn"></div>
    <div id="3" class="rate-btn-3 rate-btn"></div>
    <div id="4" class="rate-btn-4 rate-btn"></div>
    <div id="5" class="rate-btn-5 rate-btn"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="store-item-rating text-warning rate-ex2-cnt" id ="2">
    <div id="1" class="rate-btn-1 rate-btn"></div>
    <div id="2" class="rate-btn-2 rate-btn"></div>
    <div id="3" class="rate-btn-3 rate-btn"></div>
    <div id="4" class="rate-btn-4 rate-btn"></div>
    <div id="5" class="rate-btn-5 rate-btn"></div>
 </div>
```

The JS

```
$(function(){ 
        $('.rate-btn').hover(function(){
            $('.rate-btn').removeClass('rate-btn-hover');
            var therate = $(this).attr('id');
            for (var i = therate; i >= 0; i--) {
                $('.rate-btn-'+i).addClass('rate-btn-hover');
            };
        });

        $('.rate-btn').click(function(){    
            var therate = $(this).attr('id');
            var dataRate = 'act=rate&product_id=<?php echo $product_id; ?>&rate='+therate; //
            $('.rate-btn').removeClass('rate-btn-active');
            for (var i = therate; i >= 0; i--) {
                $('.rate-btn-'+i).addClass('rate-btn-active');
            };
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "inc/ajax.php",
                data: dataRate,
                success:function(){}
            });

        });
    });
```

The Count

```
        <div class="box-result-cnt">
        <?php
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_rating"); 
            while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $rate_db[] = $data;
                $sum_rates[] = $data['rate'];
            }
            if(@count($rate_db)){
                $rate_times = count($rate_db);
                $sum_rates = array_sum($sum_rates);
                $rate_value = $sum_rates/$rate_times;
                $rate_bg = (($rate_value)/5)*100;
            }else{
                $rate_times = 0;
                $rate_value = 0;
                $rate_bg = 0;
            }
        ?>
        <hr>
        <h3>The content was rated <strong><?php echo $rate_times; ?></strong> times.</h3>
        <hr>
        <h3>The rating is at <strong><?php echo $rate_value; ?></strong> .</h3>
        <hr>
        <div class="rate-result-cnt">
            <div class="rate-bg" style="width:<?php echo $rate_bg; ?>%"></div>
            <div class="rate-stars"></div>
        </div>
        <hr>

    </div>
```

Comment: Would you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can only rate 1 product (as the demo does it). To get the current rating, you can select all the ratings and average them:

```
Current rating: SELECT AVG(rate) FROM tbl_rating
Number of ratings: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_rating
```

Now if you need to know the rating for the current user:

```
SELECT rate FROM tbl_rating WHERE user_id = $userIPAdress
```

And if you add a `product_id` column to the `tbl_rating` table to be able to rate multiple product, just add a WHERE clause:

```
Current rating: SELECT AVG(rate) FROM tbl_rating WHERE product_id = $productId
Number of ratings: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_rating WHERE product_id = $productId
```

Comment: I've already added the additional column for product_id as I had noticed the same thing. The real issue that I'm having is calling the rating from each product. So, basically, product one and two are static and have ids, but I'm having issues calling the ratings and filling the stars from the index.php - seems to be something missing, some php argument that I'm either not seeing or too tired to see...

Comment: Doesn't it work with the last 2 queries? They return you the average rating (= number of stars) for a specific product as well as the number of ratings. If you want these values for ALL products, you can do this: `SELECT AVG(rate) FROM tbl_rating GROUP BY product_id` and `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_rating GROUP BY product_id`

Comment: The first one actually does work - see my update above with the code. The only issue I'm having now is assigning an id to each product that can be then called